# Grouping of the variables having more than 1000 categories

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

There are more than 60000 categories in one of the variables of a data frame. I want to group the categories as 'OTHERS' where the value count is less than 1000.
How to do that?[image]

Comment: Your question lacks detail. Add what you tried so far

Answer (score 2):

Consider mapping value counts into a new column via a dictionary, then conditionally adjust with [**`Series.where`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```py
val_dict = data['title'].value_counts().to_dict()

data['vcount'] = data['title'].replace(val_dict)
data['title'] = data['title'].where(data['vcount'].ge(1000), 'Others')
```

Comment: This is an extremely elegant solution. While my solution works, this is more efficent both in terms of lines of code and in terms of how long it would take to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a secondary column `title_updated` , and use that to `groupby`

```
temp_df = data['title'].values_counts().reset_index()
temp_df.columns = ['title','title_count']

data = pd.merge(data,temp_df,on=['title'])
```

Once you have the `title_count` , you can generate the secondary title column

```
def generate_title(inp):
    inp = inp.values
    title = inp[0]
    title_count = inp[1]
    
    if title_count < 1000:
       return 'Other'
    else:
       return title

data['title_updated'] = data[['title','title_count']].apply(generate_title,axis=1)

data['title_updated'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this, I set it up so there is a minimum number of observations and anything below that is classified as other.

Here is an example with some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        'group':['a','a','a','b','c'],
        'value':[1,2,3,4,5]
    }
)

minimum_count = 2
counts = df['group'].value_counts()
to_combine = counts[counts<minimum_count].index #Get a list of values to combine

mask = df['group'].isin(to_combine) # Get mask of values to combine

df['combined'] = df['group'] # Create a new column that will store combined values

df.loc[mask,'combined'] = 'Other' #Sets value of the columns to combine to `Other`.
```

This outputs:

```
    group   value   combined
0   a       1       a
1   a       2       a
2   a       3       a
3   b       4       Other
4   c       5       Other
```